# Advice for running a GLM for species co-occurrence that accounts for sample size?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

I am trying to conduct an analysis that looks at the co-occurrence of multiple species with a focal species. Observations of my focal species have a 60m buffer. I am counting co-occurrence as an intersection with the buffer (with appropriate temporal filtering applied to avoid overrepresenting co-occurrence). I have been trying to use a GLM with binomial distribution to model the independent variable of species type and the response variable of presence-absence within each buffer. I am having a little trouble with the analysis because I want to account for both the number of available buffers of the focal species and the different sample sizes of each secondary species. Does anyone have any thoughts on what analysis I should be using or how to treat the data? I tried to do some weighting with the GLM both with the sample size of each species and the inverse, and neither really yielded results that seemed to answer my question.

Here is a little snip of what the observation geometry looks like.
[image]

Thank you for your time - any insight would be greatly appreciated!